# Change colour of curve according to its y-value in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

there is the possibility to color the y-values according to their value in matplotlib like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm


x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(2*x)
plt.scatter(x,y, c=cm.hot(np.abs(y)), edgecolor='none')
plt.show()
```

What is the corresponding way to do it in plotly?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

N = 1000
t = np.linspace(0,10,100)
y = np.sin(t)

fig = go.Figure(
        data = [go.Scatter(x=t,y=y,mode = "lines")]
)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`plotly express` is good for working with [continuous color scales](https://plotly.com/python/builtin-colorscales/). You can use the arguments `color` and `color_continuous_scale` to specify which variable determines the color, and which color scale to use (which you can select from [here](https://plotly.com/python/builtin-colorscales/)).

EDIT: to get something more closely resembling a line, you can increase the number of markers from 100 to 10000

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

N = 1000
t = np.linspace(0,10,10000)
y = np.sin(t)

fig = px.scatter(x=t, y=y, color=y, color_continuous_scale='hot')

fig.show()
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Is there a version for px.line as well?

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider no but if you use enough markers, it will appear to be a line - I've updated my answer in case you want to see what that looks like

Answer (score 1):

**plotly** line color is per trace, hence if you only want one trace the following shows how to achieve in **graph objects** or **px** using markers and lines

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import plotly.colors
import pandas as pd

N = 1000
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(t)

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Scatter(x=t, y=y, mode="markers+lines", marker_color=np.abs(y), marker_coloraxis="coloraxis")]
).update_layout(
    coloraxis_colorscale=plotly.colors.sequential.Hot
)
fig.show()

px.scatter(
    pd.DataFrame({"x": t, "y": y, "color": np.abs(y)}),
    x="x",
    y="y",
    color="color",
    color_continuous_scale="hot",
).update_traces(mode="markers+lines")
```

#### multiple traces - trace per target color of line

- `line_color` is per trace (it cannot be defined as an array)
- hence reshape data as line segments with a trace for each target color
- note switching off legend as it becomes meaningless, plus 97 traces are created for this figure

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": t, "y": y, "color": np.abs(y)})

fig = px.line(
    x=np.array([df["x"], df["x"].shift(-1).ffill(), np.full(len(df), np.nan)]).ravel(
        order="F"
    ),
    y=np.array([df["y"], df["y"].shift(-1).ffill(), np.full(len(df), np.nan)]).ravel(
        order="F"
    ),
    color=np.repeat(plotly.colors.sample_colorscale("hot", df["color"]), 3),
).update_traces(mode="lines").for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(line_color=t.name))

print(len(fig.data))

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
```

[image]

Comment: What does "per trace" mean? Is there also a solution for the continous case (mode = "lines")?

Comment: updated answer to deomonstrate.   it's the fundamentals of the plotly object model.  a line is an object which has a color attribute